# Word for "personify" when you're talking about an animal

Tags: meaning

For example:

"The moose personifies Maine's wilderness."

I know personify isn't correct since it's not ascribing *human* form to the wilderness, but it does animate it and bring it to life in a way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [*embody*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embody) is an alternative in this situation.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if there is a specific word that applies to animals, but *[epitomizes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epitomize)* would work for just about anything, including an animal.

Answer (score 1):

A personification for an animal for example a sandpiper would be strutting. It would be a great personification since it explains how the sandpiper walks in arrogance which shows a human quality, which is why strutting came to my mind for this great question. Thanks and hope you like my answer. Bye!

Answer (score 0):

As an animal equivalent of 'personify' since this latter word seems to apply only to humans, I suggest using the Latin word animus, which means spirit or other related things (check your Latin dictionary) to form the word 'animify', which would connote the meaningful concept being ignored in an anthropocentric culture such as ours.

Comment: Is this word in circulation? Or are you suggesting the OP use a coined term?